# How use module @stripe/stripe-react-native in older react native project class component?

Tags: react-native

I want to use the latest stripe sdk   @stripe/stripe-react-native in older react native project based in class component ?
The doc stripe use the hooks,there is no example that used class component,So need help and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the stripe functions can be imported directly from `@stripe/stripe-react-native` so that you can use them both with `class` and `functional` components.
However, you are also able to access them via dedicated `hooks`.
For instance you can use `useConfirmPayment` hook which apart from `confirmPayment` method provides also `loading` state so you don't need to handle it manually.
Moreover, there is also the main `useStripe` hook which provides all of the stripe methods.
examples:

1.

```js
import { useConfirmPayment } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';

const { confirmPayment, loading } = useConfirmPayment();

// await confirmPayment(...)
```

2. 

```js
import { useStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';

const { confirmPayment } = useStripe();

// await confirmPayment(...)
```

3. 

```js
import { confirmPayment } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';

// await confirmPayment(...)
```

Source: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/docs/tipsi-stripe-migration-guide.md#class-vs-functional-components